# Is a monad functor also known as a monad map?

Tags: ct.category-theory, monads

Suppose I have a monad $M_S = \langle S , \eta_S, \mu_S \rangle$.  I want to map this monad to another monad, $M_Q = \langle Q , \eta_Q, \mu_Q \rangle$.  What is the minimum I have to define to give this monad map?  Can it be defined just with a natural transformation $F: S \rightarrow Q$.  Is there a freedom to just map one or both of the natural transformations to new natural transformations?

I am looking at [Street 72](https://scholar.google.ca/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=the+theory+of+monads&btnG=#d=gs_qabs&t=1672331794323&u=%23p%3DlElF9Ic5_U0J) and in it he defines a monad functor.

[image]

Is this the same as a monad map?  If so, it looks like you need to define a natural transformation $\phi: S \rightarrow Q$, since $U$ in their notation is identity if we stay on the same base category.  Is the monad functor the same as a monad map?  I mean, are they saying that a monad functor takes a monad to another monad always?   Why don't we have the freedom to change the natural transformations to give a new monad?  Why don't we have to check/change the natural transformations?

Comment: There are two different notions of monad morphisms. One applies to monads on a same fixed category and are just natural transformation satisfying axioms of compatiblity to the monad structure. The other (referred to here as monad functor) is for monads on different categories, and involve both a functor between the underlying categories and a natural transformation. The first kind of morphism can be seen as a special case when the "functor" pat is the identity. So, what I think you call "monad map" is the special case of a "monad functor" when $U$ is the identity functor.

Comment: Maybe worth noting that the direction of the arrow is a matter of convention when working with monads on a fixed category...

Answer (score 2):

$\require{AMScd}$I have thought a bit about this recently, because (surprisingly) there is no source that explains the matter in a clear comprehensive fashion: as far as I remember Street doesn't make this simple remark in his paper.

He defines a 2-category $Mnd(Cat)$ (in fact, $Mnd(K)$ for every 2-category $K$) and right after, an obvious functor $Und:Mnd(Cat)\to Cat$ "projecting on the first component", i.e. sending a monad $(C,t)$ to the category $C$, a morphism $(U,\phi) : (C,t)\to (D,s)$ to $U : C\to D$, and similarly on 2-cells.

Now: this definition of a monad morphism is "correct", and modeled on the idea that a monoid is its own regular representation, so monad morphisms shall be equivariant maps (intertwiners: you see why a morphism in the sense of Street is such thing); but what about the good old (and true) motto that a monad is a monoid in the category of endofunctors? Shouldn't then morphisms of monads be monoid homomorphisms, i.e. natural transformations $\alpha : t\Rightarrow s$ such that the usual algebra morphism diagrams
$$\begin{CD}
tt @>\alpha*\alpha>> ss @.@. 1 @>\eta^t>> t\\
@V\mu^tVV@VV\mu^sV @.@| @VV\alpha V\\
t @>>\alpha> s @.@. 1 @>>\eta^s> s
\end{CD}$$
commute?

Well, yes!

So is there a way to relate the two definitions?

Well, yes [whew.jpeg meme]! And the first definition is "correct" because it allows to recover the second: look again at the functor $Und:Mnd(Cat)\to Cat$: its "fiber" over $C$, i.e. the category having objects all the monads $(C,t)$ on $C$ and morphisms the monad maps such that $Und(U,\phi)=id_C$ (so, $U$ is the identity functor, and $\phi : t\Rightarrow s$) is made exactly of the $\phi$'s (specializing Street's diagrams at the beginning of p151) that are "monoid homomorphisms".